# How to apply border spacing with CSS

Tags: html, css

What i have so far (some sort of example, not real):

html:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="article">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#article {
  color:red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

THE PROBLEM!

**I cannot divide the border at the bottom and the div itself**

this may help you>>
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22271794/div.PNG

SOLVED!!

**HR TAG HELPED ME!!
Search Google for> HR TAG STYLING AND THAT'S IT (MARGIN ZERO, CHANGE COLOR)**

Comment: Try adding margin and/or padding.

Comment: I recommend you read more tutorials or documentation about CSS, and also try to improve the way you ask questions. A little less shouting and some more effort will get you a long way :)

Comment: Please provide the solution that you used, in the form of a new answer to your own question, so that this question will be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

just set a `padding-bottom` to the div itself, e.g.

```
#article {
   color          : red;
   border-bottom  : 1px solid black;
   padding-bottom : 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The border is placed at the bottom of the `div`. That's the point and there isn't anything you can do about that. If you want it to be visually separated from the content inside the div, you should add some padding at the bottom.

Comment: already tried that :( it's just expanding the div itself (with it's color too), it doesn't nothing else

Comment: yea, padding expands the div. If you want the border to actually be separated from the div, you'll need to put in a completely different element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `padding` or `margin`? 
With those you can style the placement of the div and its border.

```
#article {
color:red;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

<strike>If this is not what you mean, what do you mean with dividing a border?</strike> This is not what you meant.

Edit: After seeing that image you added, i think you should find some other solution then pure css. 
I would see an solution with a div that contains some element that hugs the bottom, and is white of color.

```
<div id="article">
<div></div>
</div>

#article {
color:red;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}

#article div {
// add some positioning. 
margin-top: 99%; 
height: 1%;
color: white;
}
```

This should give you some control over that whitespace you need. 
Again, I don't think it is possible to do this on CSS alone.

Comment: thank you alot, FEEDBACK SENT, but using the hr tag is much simplier

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an image then you can just do it like this:

```
img {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dseSm/)

But if you're using a `div` with a background then you could do it using an extra div to produce the gap. Eg:

```
<div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="space"></div>
    <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#content {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
}

#space {
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}

#border {
    width:200px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
}
```

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dseSm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with CSS, but probably not the most cross-browser friendly way of doing things.

html

```
<div>Text Here</div>
```

css

```
div, div:after {
    display:block;
    background:#00f;
    width:100px;
}

div:after {
    content:" ";
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/2BQ8f/